# Django form not showing up on admin page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-1.8

I have a contact form/model in Django that isn't showing up on the admin management page.
I have no idea why it isn't showing up, I have tried to debug by running migrations, and also renaming some of the model variables.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    their_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    their_name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(label='Message', max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs = {'id': 'Message_form'}))
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact
admin.register(Contact)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .models import Contact
from .forms import ContactForm
...

def contact(request):

    valid_input = 'no input'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        valid_input = 'invalid input'
        TheForm = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if TheForm.is_valid():
            valid_input = 'valid input'
            name = TheForm['name']
            email = TheForm['email']
            message = TheForm['message']
            Contact.objects.create(name=name, email=email, message=message)
    else:
        TheForm = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'BlogHome/pages/contact.html', {'TheForm': TheForm, 'valid_input': valid_input})
```

Could this be the way I am importing the model? I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Comment: What do the form and the view have to do with the admin page?

Comment: The model that the form is associated with isn't showing up.

Comment: In the admin? Well, have you included the app in INSTALLED_APPS? Again, though, this has nothing to do with the view and the form, which are not used in the admin.

Comment: Yes. This app is in the INSTALLED_APPS. The reason I mentioned the form is because the form having a model has caused problems for me in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **admin.py** create an admin class for your Contact model and after register this model in admin using that class.

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'their_name', 'email', 'message') 

admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```