# Django/Python - I don't use my django admin page to Add information my site because the admin field is empty

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm not sure what happened but for the first time ever, i'm unable to use my admin fields. The fields are empty, and i can't use the models i can created on Django. I tried creating a new project but still no luck and i don't know how to resolve this.

My Models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class PersonModel(models.Model):

    Gender = {
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
    }
    Adult = {
        ('Non-Adult','Non-Adult'),
        ('Adult','Adult'),
    }
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True),
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True),
    The_gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True),
    The_Adult = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

my admin.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PersonModel

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(PersonModel)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import PersonModel

# Create your views here.
def Home(request):
    Persons = PersonModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Practice_2_app/Home.html',
    {'Persons':Persons})

def The_form(request):
    return render(request, 'Practice_2_app/The_form.html',
    {})
```

[image: This is how my admin fields looks like]

Comment: Have you run the command python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate?

Comment: Hi Pablo, yes i did. A few times to. This didn't work.

Comment: That is quite unusual. Try creating an AdminModel, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42053542/7100120)

Comment: Hi Niko, I have made the change on myside, and I haven't been successful unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I copied your code to a local project of my own and figured out your problem:

You have commas at the end of all of your lines in your model definition, so you've accidentally defined a bunch of tuples which are not valid fields in your model. If you look in your migrations, you can see that your `PersonModel` only has an id field, which would explain why you see an empty form in the admin.

```py
# Generated by Django 3.2 on 2022-12-26 19:52

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PersonModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Previous:

It looks like your app is setup correctly, but the forms are simply not being rendered. The models are clearly registered so I don't think there's anything wrong with your models or admin code. Here are some things to try:

Make sure you aren't overriding any of the default admin templates with custom code or with code from other packages. I'd try a couple of things. Remove any installed Django packages that could be overriding built in admin templates. With no luck there, you can try visiting in a different browser, try visiting with add-ons disabled, try visiting in incognito mode to make sure it's actually a problem with your dev setup. I'd also try re-installing Django in your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe rename `. models` to `.models`?  <-not a problem

can you try it like this?

```
from django.contrib import admin
@admin.register(PersonModel)
class PersonModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['date', 'name', 'surname', 'the_gender', 'the_adult',]
```

Comment: This isn't it, I thought it wouldn't import it but it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Hi Vinko, I have just made the change. I'm still not in luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to register default user model unless you have created your own custom admin.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PersonModel

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User, PersonModel)
```

If it doesn't work, could you also try to unregister the default user model and then register again the default one along with the custom created model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PersonModel

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User, PersonModel)
```